# Comparing key content in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Lets say I have two dictionaries with the same keys

```
dict1 = {first_letter: a, second_letter:b , third_letter: c}

dict2 = {first_letter: a, second_letter:b , third_letter: d}
```

I have the same keys but I want to compare the content inside of keys and print the intersections

so if there was another dictionary called

```
intersection = {}
```

I'd want the results

```
print intersection

{a,b}
```

I have the two dictionaries from two files, and I just want to have the intersection of the two files in one other file. So if the keys contain the same value then store it into another file and print it out.

Here is my code:

```
keys = ['lastname', 'firstname', 'email', 'id', 'phone']
dicts = []
second_dicts = []
third_dicts = []
intersection = []

with open("oldFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Split each line.
        line = line.strip().split()
        # Create dict for each row.
        d = dict(zip(keys, line))
        # Print the row dict
        print d

        # Store for future use
        dicts.append(d)

print "\n\n"
with open ("newFile.txt") as n:
    for line in n:
        # Split each line.
        line = line.strip().split()
        # Create dict for each row.
        r = dict(zip(keys, line))
        # Print the row dict
        print r
        # Store for future use
        second_dicts.append(r)


print"\n\n"

#shared_items = set(dicts.items()) & set(second_dicts.items())

#print shared_items
#if oldFile has the same content as newFile then make a a newFile 
#called intersectionFile and print
```

Comment: Intersection is a set not a dictionary.

Comment: You need to clarify "intersection". If `d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` and `d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}`, what is their intersection? If it's `{1, 2}`, @mirosval's answer is correct. If it's the empty set, @AvinashRaj is correct.

Comment: but I get the error 





   print set(dicts.values()) & set(second_dicts.values())
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this,

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2 , 'c': 3}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 1, 'b':2 , 'c': 4}
>>> {dict1[i] for i in dict1 if dict1[i]==dict2[i]}
set([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set(dict1.values()) & set(dict2.values())
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection

Comment: I keep getting " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' "

Comment: from 

intersection = set(dicts.values()) & set(second_dicts.values())

Comment: Are you sure then that your `dicts` and `second_dicts` are dictionaries and not lists?

Comment: Oh shoot you're right... Let me post up my code I think that will be more useful...

Comment: You should probably let OP know that your answer does something different from what @AvinashRaj did earlier, and his/her example is ambiguous as to which one s/he wants.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted?

```
dict1 = {a: 1, b:2 , c: 3}
dict2 = {a: 1, b:2 , c: 4}

common = []
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if dict2[key] == value:
        common.append(value)

intersection = set(common)
print intersection
```